# How do I add a folder to the .gitignore file?

Tags: git, ignore

There is a folder with images in my repository that I don't want to push to my GitHub repo because they are temp files and every time I test my model, I delete the images.  Git sees this as a change and wants to track and commit these images to my remote GitHub repository.  The list of images displays on my screen every time I write "git status".  Is there any way I can add this folder of images to my .gitignore file so I don't have to scroll through a list of a thousand images every time I write git status?  Thanks for your help.